# Are there limitations on number of When statements with SQL CASE WHEN?

Tags: sql, netsuite

I've setup a CASE WHEN formula below (Is in NetSuite but I believe is the same syntax as SQL)

If I remove one of the WHEN statements it runs succesfully.
Is there a max number of When statements that can be used with Case When?
Is there a better way to structure this query with very similar WHEN's, eg could multiple transaction.status fields with the same output be combined?

```
 CASE  WHEN {transaction.type}='Sales Order' AND{transaction.status}='Closed' THEN 0  
- WHEN {transaction.type}='Sales Order' AND {transaction.status}='Cancelled' THEN 0  
- WHEN {transaction.type}='Sales Order' AND {transaction.status}='Pending Fulfillment' THEN 1  
- WHEN {transaction.type}='Sales Order' AND {transaction.status}='Partially Fulfilled' THEN 1  
- WHEN {transaction.type}='Sales Order' AND {transaction.status}='Pending Billing' THEN 1 
- WHEN {transaction.type}='Sales Order' AND {transaction.status}='Pending Billing/Partially Fulfilled' THEN 1  
- WHEN {transaction.type}='Sales Order' AND {transaction.status}='Billed' THEN 1  
- WHEN {transaction.type}='Invoice' AND {transaction.createdfrom}IS NULL AND {transaction.status}='Paid In Full' THEN 1  
- WHEN {transaction.type}='Invoice' AND {transaction.createdfrom} IS NULL AND {transaction.status}='Open' THEN 1  
- ELSE 0 END
```

Many thanks

Comment: Is it irrelevant, which statement you delete? Does it happen only at one specific case or everytime you remove one, regardless which one?

Comment: Plus I see that you can maybe nest your case conditions as you always check for `transaction.type` that should be either `Sales Order` or `Invoice`, maybe you can outsource the check for this field in an exterior `CASE` block and check the second condition with an interior. This way you would reduce the number of cases per block

Comment: Although there might be a limit on the number of conditions in a `case` expression, that limit is way. more than 10.  You probably just have a bug in your logic.

Comment: Have you picked the right tool here? Are you using `CASE` when you could just be performing boolean logic with `AND` and `OR`?

Comment: Thanks @procra  Being that the status is unique for all of these I've been able to add the doc type or Sales Order and Invoice as criteria.  Getting rid of the AND looks like it's done the trick, cheers

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff  I feel like it was tied up with 'Partially Fulfilled' status, I narrowed it down to that line but I couldn't find a typo - there has to be something.

Comment: thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever  I think so, in this case, I need to work out an overally quantity for a product in transactions. You're probably right with being able to use AND OR too,  I'll give this a go next opportunity, am just starting out with SQL